# Can anyone recommend colored 100% silicone caulk for use in a shower?

Tags: shower, caulking, caulk

I have a shower with a tan colored grout. I need to put silicone caulk in the spot where the walls meet the floor. The previous owner used grout there and it is all cracked out.

I'm having trouble finding 100% silicone caulk that has colors. I can only find one, made by "Custom Building Products":

[image]

I'm not sure what "commercial" means, is it not meant for household use? Can anyone recommend any others that I can buy in the US? I can find others that are "siliconized", but I read that you're supposed to use 100% silicone).

(I'm not sure if it's ok to mention brands on this site, but I'm stuck I don't want to use the wrong product for this job, and not sure where else to ask).

Thanks

Comment: have you tried your local big box store or tile store? This is common stuff, I cant imagine its hard to find.

Comment: yeah looking at home depot website the above is the only one I can find (order only) - Lowes doesn't offer any colored types that are 100% silicone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take; the newer siliconized calks are excellent products.  I think you will be impressed with their performance. Regarding the above selection, I wouldn't let the 'commercial' labeling impede your choice.  This product will also work.